# How to change the maximum number of members-by-relationship for given membership types?

Tags: civimember

I want to change the settings for the maximum allowable memberships by dint of the relationship with the primary member. I can easily modify this number in the membership type settings, but this doesn't reflect in the current memberships for any member - they continue to display the old limits.

Can I force this change into current memberships, do I have to wait until the membership is renewed, or am I stuck with the old settings?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the DB try changing the value in civicrm_membership.max_related

Answer (score 1):

I bet you that if you hit Edit on the Relationship [someone previously not inheriting the Membership] - and then Save (without changing anything) - they now do inherit the Membership as you intended right?

So the Q is not just how do you change the maximum number of membership - but it's really about how do propagate that across.

You need to automate the trigger - I'm thinking an extension that essentially does an update Membership without updating the Membership.

Ok we can test that in the API explorer! 
/civicrm/api#explorer

I just tried this on one of my sites:

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Membership', 'create', array(
  'sequential' => 1,
  'membership_type_id' => "Fort Smith Kayak Club - Family",
  'contact_id' => 2,
));
```

Trying to update my own Individual Membership to a Family Membership - and that worked in that I inherited all my kids on this Family one.

Point is - updating the Membership via the API triggers a 'check to see how many should inherit'

So I recommend a small custom extension that loads Memberships and 'updates' them. That should work!